# Getting an unexpected end of input error on a fresh template created Angular project

Tags: c#, node.js, angular, typescript

I created a fresh project using Visual Studio's Angular with ASP.net template and on first build I get the error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Unexpected end of input
See "/private/var/folders/kd/060hv6cj1j10wddm4h7sc50r0000gn/T/ng-BFqD9a/angular-errors.log" for further details.
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy.SpaProxyLaunchManager[0]
      Couldn't start the SPA development server with command 'npm start'.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy.SpaProxyLaunchManager: Error: Couldn't start the SPA development server with command 'npm start'.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy.SpaProxyLaunchManager[0]
      No SPA development server running at https://localhost:44487 found.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy.SpaProxyLaunchManager: Information: No SPA development server running at https://localhost:44487 found.
  PID   TT  STAT      TIME COMMAND
84889   ??  S      0:00.82 /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet /Users/jacklohse/repos/AidanBoard/AidanBoard/bin/Debug/net7.0/AidanBoard.dll
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy.SpaProxyMiddleware[0]
      SPA proxy is not ready. Returning temporary landing page.
```

After finding my angular-errors.log file I see this error:

```
[error] SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at ESMLoader.moduleStrategy (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:119:18)
    at ESMLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:468:14)
```

I saw some people saying this was an issue with node.js but I tried both LTS and Recent versions and nothing changed. I really don't know what the issue is and I am going insane. Please Help!

I tried to run the project from visual studio and command line.
I expected the default template SPA to show up but npm run start failed.
I found that npm run start was failing because of an unexpected end of input error.

Comment: You likely have a malformed HTML template.

Comment: Check the versión Angular use the "fresh tenplate". Check versión of npm, typescript and LTS requeriments. Sometimes need a less versions that the last